# C++ block with VIM surround plugin

Tags: c++, vim, surround

I know how to use vim's surround plugin to add brackets to a c++ block as follows:

before:

```
if (condition)
    bla1
    bla2
```

after:

```
if (condition)
{    
    bla1
    bla2
}
```

But what if I want the end result to be:

```
if (condition) {    
    bla1
    bla2
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way to do that, but you could place your cursor on the `if` line, and do `Shift+J` (in normal mode) to join the current line to the next one.

Comment: Worst case scenario this is a good way. I am just wondering if it can be done purely by surround's functionality